# Multiplied background with custom params in SASS

Tags: css, sass, mixins, background-image

I'm trying to set some multiple background @mixin with SASS, so this is my code:

```
@mixin background_multiplied($background_1, $background_2: false, $background_3: false) {
  $params: url('../#{$background_1}') $atributes;

  @if $background_2 != false {
    $params: url('../#{$background_1}') $atributes, url('../#{$background_2}') $atributes;
  }
  @if $background_3 != false {
    $params: url('../#{$background_2}') $atributes, url('../#{$background_2}') $atributes, url('../#{$background_3}') $atributes;
  }

  @each $attr in $atributes {
    @if $attr == position_horizontal {
      $position_horizontal: center
    }
    @if $attr == position_vertical {
      $position_vertical: top
    }
    @if $attr == bg_repeat {
      $bg_repeat: no-repeat
    }
    @if $attr == bg_size {
      $bg_size: auto
    }
  }

  background: $params;
}
```

Something is not right bc i have `error (Line 210: Undefined variable: "$atributes".)`
Can anybody help me? Much thx.

Answer (score 2):

The error speaks for itself. You've got the `$atributes` variable called everywhere, but it's never declared.

Comment: so where I need to put them?

Comment: The same place you "put them" when you declared the other variables you're using?